# Using one jumper wire between two light switches connections please

Tags: electrical

Which screw do I use ( top or bottom) for a jumper wire connecting two light switches

Comment: Are you trying to operate a light fixture from two independent switches? If so, you need to understand 3 way switches.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the one with the permanent live.

The switches don't care which end you use, but if you connect to the switched live side you'll be switching both circuits at once, the second switch would then only work when the first was on.

I'm assuming this is in one switch unit, feeding two lamps from the same incoming live. If it's for a 2/3/4-way switch, you need to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single pole switch you can use either screw.  The switch simply opens or closes a circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The switches do not care.

Top or bottom or even top to bottom on the other switch.

I believe most simple switches use the bottom for hot and top for switch hot.  Switch is on when flipped/pushed up.